# Fastest way to reset or free copy-on-write mapped area

Tags: mmap

I have a CoW region of memory that I need to reset to the original state.

Sadly, MADV_DONTNEED behaves exactly the same as munmap, and is seemingly freeing all pages. *munmap* is extremely expensive and the performance is horrendous to say the least, and its *way* cheaper to create a new $thing from scratch using MAP_ANONYMOUS, initialize it manually, then munmap that. That makes zero sense to me, and just shows something is really broken with mmap and CoW mappings. Unfortunately for me I really need CoW. It's that or memcpy from one range to another, and since we are in 2021 I expect that Linux will be able to do copy-on-write.

See: https://kostja.github.io/2012/04/04/1111.html

I would like to only discard the dirty pages of my memory range.

```
munmap anon: 435110ns (435 micros)
munmap memfd: 21958015ns (21958 micros)
```

This is the average time when freeing 400x 128MB ranges. If I only free 1 range then I get sane numbers, so there's some kind of bad scaling going on in the kernel that I don't understand. The tmpfs-backed area is untouched after allocating it with MAP_NORESERVE. This is completely insane. Are memfd (tmpfs-backed) files just that slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way ended up being to use the hardware virtualization itself to implement copy-on-write mechanisms. It ended up being extremely complex, fraught with footguns, but most importantly very fast. It is possible to use just a few pages of working memory to call into a copy-on-write VM. Most of the pages are duplicated page table entries.

Additionally, this opens up the possibility for copies of copies, as well as flattening a copy-on-write VM so that it can be used as master.

Linux has no support for this whatsoever.